# How to indicate the default value in a dropdown menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, default

I have a form containing a number of dropdown menu's. Each dropdown has a default option. I know how to set this default value, but I'm not sure on how to indicate this value, so that people know that is the default.

I create the dropdown like this

```
<?php
    for ($mismatch = 0; $mismatch <= 3; $mismatch ++) {
        if($mismatch == 1){
            $select_mismatch .= "<option value = $mismatch selected > ".$mismatch." (default) </option>";
        } else {
            $select_mismatch .= "<option value = $mismatch > ".$mismatch." </option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

So on the web page, the dropdown looks like:

```
option 1 (default)
option 2
option 3
```

So now I indicate the default value by just adding `(default)` to it. Does anyone know another way to indicate this which is a bit more pleasing to the eye?

Comment: I think you have height on your dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select data-placeholder="Please Select" class="required select-full" name="status" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1" <?php if ($post['status'] == "1") { ?> selected="true" <?php } ?>>Enable</option>
                <option value="0" <?php if ($post['status'] == "0") { ?> selected="true" <?php } ?>>Disable</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: I know how to create it, I'm just not sure on how to show it in the form itself

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this?

```
<select name="test"> 
    <option> 
    1 
    </option> 
    <option> 
    2 
    </option> 
    <option selected> 
    3 
    </option> 
    <option> 
    4 
    </option> 
    <option> 
    5 
    </option> 
</select>
```

Unless you mean to a drop down hover menu?
if so then you could add a colour to the default option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a CSS class to indicate.

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5jh2t85q/)

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">please choose</option>
    <option value="2" class="default">default</option>
    <option value="3">other item</option>
</select>

.default{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```